# What probability distribution do you fit to 'differences' between percentages (can take both negative and positive values)?

Tags: distributions, generalized-linear-model, differences

I have some data about fisheries and there is a variable which denotes differences between two percentages and hence has both negative and positive values. I want to run a model with this as a dependent variable. This or its log transformed values do not fit a normal distribution when tested with a Shapiro test. It is falling close to a logistic distribution when tested with 'fitdistrplus' in R but not able to understand how that can be the case. How do I go about this if I want to run a glm?
Thank you in advance.

[image: This is a simple histogram of the values.]

Comment: Shapiro test could mean Shapiro-Wilk (I guess) or Shapiro-Francia (I guess not).

Comment: If X ~ U(0, 1) then μ + β(log(X) − log(1 − X)) ~ Logistic(μ, β). Not sure that is relevant but R may be showing something like that. Your variable is bounded by -100% to +100%  so that in the sense that it is bounded, it may be related to the beta distribution. I would divide values by 2 and add 1, then search for a distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you log transformed this, but logarithms of negative values are complex  numbers and logarithm of zero is undefined. In short, logarithmic transformation makes no sense statistically for such a variable. If you look carefully at your results, you should see lots of missing values (NAs).

Further, set aside the zero and negative values on your scale and imagine it translated to all positive numbers. There is still another problem, as your distribution is approximately symmetric. Logarithmic transformation of a symmetric distribution can never bring it closer to normality.

At most, you could use something like $\text{sign}(y) \log(1 + |y|)$ but that kind of transformation is usually needed only if $y$ can take on both very large positive values and very large negative values (e.g. profit (or loss)). Here the bounds $[-100, 100]$  rule that out.

What distribution it is, however, is not really material if you want to apply regression. Regression doesn't entail an assumption about the marginal distribution of the response, although some flavours of regression may be better than others here.

- I wouldn't rule out absolutely plain or vanilla regression, but watch carefully for impossible predicted values.
- You could map from $[-100, 100]$ to $[0, 1]$ by $(\text{difference} + 100) / 200$ and then logit and beta regression are in range. That procedure respects the bounds. But you need to choose distribution family carefully (and look out for more realistic standard error calculations).

Percentage difference is, however, a fragile metric and it is entirely possible that the extreme values are moderate outliers not just in terms of the response but on other variables too.

It's hard to be confident of anything without more information, except that plain logarithmic transformation can't be what you want.

The bounds rule out a normal in the strict sense, and also a logistic in the strict sense. Both normal and logistic are in principle unbounded, although that doesn't stop the normal being a good fit when it is (e.g. often to adult heights).

Scatter plots of this outcome and leading predictors in a scatter plot matrix would be very helpful.

EDIT

In a comment the transformation used was revealed as taking logarithms after adding 100, which takes care of the negative values (and works for all given no $-$100 in the data). Here I mocked up a sample from a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 30, showing that such a transformation *imparts* negative skew. The plots are quantile normal plots before and after transformation and the logarithms are natural.

It's salutary to plot $\log(y + 100)$ over the interval $(-100, 100]$ as it doesn't have the kind of behaviour you should want over the entirety of possible values.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I actually tried the following transformation log(Y+100). I misreported in my question. Apologies for that. I will try the second suggestion you have provided and examine the errors carefully in order to infer.